# twitter api error

Tags: python, twitter

I get this error when I try to enter my user name and password:

```
client = twitter.Api(username="hinakhan@yahoo.com", password="random")
```

-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    client = twitter.Api(username="hinakhan@yahoo.com", password="random")
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

Comment: check the API/Doc, the error message seems to say that you can't have `(username=` in your call. I am not familiar with the API. Maybe it's a different keyword such as `userid` ..?

Comment: username and password are not valid arguments in the Api.  See source for Api class here: http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/source/browse/twitter.py.  Arguments should be things like `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working on old documentation which is now expire.You need to read and consult with the new documentation and work with it.This error may also occur due to conffusion in libraries you need to check that you read the correct documentation or mixing up others

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/), the `twitter.Api` class does not accept a `username` argument. You may be following some outdated information.  Remember that Twitter no longer permits password authentication and [requires the use of OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq).